# How to use background image in css with spring boot?

Tags: html, css, spring-boot

I try to use jpg files for the background in my project but I can't do this via .css files.

First of all - it seems all settings are right, since the setting from the HTML file works fine:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Home page</title>
</head>
<style>
body {
    background-image: url("img/mainpage.jpg");
}
</style>
...
```

And when I include my CSS file and use background-color, it also works fine:

- main.css:

```
body {
    background-color: #193340;
}
```

But not for background-image. Even when I use both options, only color option is applied:

- main.css:

```
body {
    background-color: #193340;
    background-image: url("img/mainpage.jpg");
}
```

## how to correctly set the image file exactly in .css file?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

---

Pretty sure you are not refering to image path right inside the main.css file.

```
background-image: url("img/mainpage.jpg");
```

Try to write down correct relative path to your image.
if let's say your file structure is like this

```
index.html
img/mainpage.jpg
css/main.css
```

then correct way to your refer to image file will be

```
background-image: url("../img/mainpage.jpg")
```